# Moving the bottom margin to make space for footnotes

Tags: luatex, footnotes, layout

I saw a lot of similar questions, but didn’t see any response. I’m want the footnotes to appear below the main body of text, without changing the size of the main body. Only in case of a footnote that is too big (it should have it’s own bottom margin, lower than the margin of the main text), I want it to move the main body of text up. Here’s an approximate idea of what I’m looking for (sorry for my paint skills)[image: The page layout]

Here’s the closest I got so far

```
\begin{luacode}
function enlarge_page()
  tex.print("\\enlargethispage{\\custom_distance}")
end
\end{luacode}

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
  \directlua{enlarge_page()} % Call the Lua function to enlarge the page
  \oldfootnote{#1}%
}
```

which is to say, not very far: the distance of displacement is incorrect, doesn’t take into account the number of lines in a footnote, the different separation between the first footnote and the text, and between the footnotes themselves. Any attempt to include more details resulted in an error message. I’m using the memoir class. Is there any way to achieve this?

UPD: I do not use Lua anywhere else, so if there is a solution in XeLaTex, I can use that

UPD2: Here’s roughly the logic I’m looking for:

```
if footnote in page : lower bottom margin by a specific constant amount
for every footnote in page : lower bottom margin by distance between footnotes + (footnote length/55)* line height 
% There are roughly 55 characters per line in the footnotes
if bottom margin < the lowest possible point: bottom margin = the lowest possible point.
```

I think this should be possible in Lua, considering I managed to lower the margin for every footnote.

Comment: Looking at [how TeX handles insertions](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb11-4/tb30salomon.pdf), this would likely require making significant changes to the output routine.

Comment: Footnotes are supposed to fit into the text area, not the footer area.  You could do it with flowfram and \footnotemark, but the actual footnotes would have to be added in the preamble, or at least one would need to reserve space there.